# Why media player is still playing when I press back button

Tags: android, media-player, back-button

I know that we can use `onPause()` event to stop the MediaPlayer using `reset()` method. But I want to know why media player is still playing when I press back button?

Comment: Have you tried pausing the media player by overriding [`Activity#onBackPressed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your media player is being run by a Service. So when you press *back* key, it only destroys the Activity, not the Service. So you need to stop the service too in your activity's **onStop** method

Comment: Oh, I think you're right. I've used a separate thread for media player. but not a service.

Comment: In `vogella.de` blog, i found this description : `If you use threads in Activities their are still connected to the life-cycle of Activities and the Android system may decide to terminate them at any point in point.` So I still don't know why media player is keep playing when my main activity is terminated!

Answer (score 1):

you can stop media playing in

onBackPress() method...

Comment: Thank you, but as I said, I am searching for a reason.